# Qt QML/C++ translucent window has glitches and performance problems on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, qt, macos, qml, qt-quick

I've developed a `Qt/QML` application which I display with a translucent `QDeclarativeView` in a translucent frameless `QMainWindow` (see [this](http://www.lothlorien.com/kf6gpe/?p=204)). The application is fairly complex with a a few `ListViews` inside and some threads that poll a remote server for data and feed the views. The program runs flawlessly and at full speed without glitches on Windows 7. But when I compile and run it on Snow Leopard I've got the following problems;

- GUI rendering is slow in general
- When I scroll the `ListView` with the mouse wheel, the wheel actions affect the underlying window and my GUI flickers as if it can't render fast enough. Also often when I click something on my GUI, the mouse click just passes through my window onto the underlying window and brings it in front.
- Mouse actions feel awkward. There is a significant delay.

These problems are present on both the Release and Debug builds with/without gdb attached.

The problems sound related to me but I'm confused. Why would an application running perfectly on Win7 perform badly on Snow Leopard ? Am I missing some specific configuration ?

Comment: Does Qt on OSX use the underlying Cocoa API or the Carbon API? (Or is it using X11, which would definitely be suboptimal?)

Comment: It uses Cocoa API. I'm using the 4.7.2 version.

Comment: So it's not an "old API" problem. Might instead be an impedance mismatch (i.e., if the internal model of Qt just doesn't fit with the expected model of Cocoa) but I emphasize that I'm just guessing here.

Comment: I'm building Qt 4.7.3 from sources. Maybe it makes a difference :S

Comment: I have filed a bug report with minimal sample attached. http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-19235

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem? I'm having the same issue, although my transparent dialog is not as complex as you described yours above. It seems scroll wheel events "leak through" to the window beneath the transparent list view. Btw. I found a similar effect when dragging a WebView in QML - as long as the animation for dragging is still processed, all click events are passed through to the window below the transparent web view window. I'm developing with OSX 10.6.4, Cocoa, 64bit.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find a solution yet. We've released our application for Windows only for the moment but waiting for the Qt people to respond to our bug request. Someone having the same issue has commented under the bug report I filed. Is that you ? If not then sign-up on the bug report page and vote up the issue.